# Managing 1000s of Solana addresses and private keys on an exchange

Tags: token, send-transaction, airdrop

I plan to pre-generate a Solana address to my 1000+ user base and store it in my database. I plan to air drop each user free community tokens. Also I will have a simple user interface on my site to send these tokens out:

- Is there a cli command where I can just pass in the user's private key to create a send transaction?
- Do I need to prefund each address with some solana first so they can send the tokens out?

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need a user's private key to send them tokens.
- You can use `spl-token transfer` CLI to send it using their public key. See cookbook example: https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens
- If you want them to be able to send tokens independently (eg. using Phantom wallet) then they'll need SOL to be able to pay fees for those transactions
- If you only need them to be able to send transactions within your platform, then you have the option of making yourself the fee payer and signing the transactions

Comment: I give them access to their private key that they can import into Phantom, but they won't be able to send it else where since they don't have any SOL. I just wanted to see if there is a work around to that. So when I do a **spl-token transfer**, it must be the contract creator right? What if I wanted to do this transfer with another account?

Comment: You'd be able to have your site create transactions with you paying the fees, but that's quite limiting compared to being able to use the wallet however they like. `spl-token transfer` will use your local Solana config, so you can switch the keypairs. You could also write a script (NodeJS or w/e you like) if you want more flexibility, there's examples of code for that in the cookbook too.